# Every finite group is contained in $S_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory

I am reading about the inverse Galois problem. I stumbled with the problem of showing that every finite group is contained in $S_p$ for a large enough prime $p$, is this true? does anybody have a hint on how to prove this or any references I can consult?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to prove that every finite group is contained in $S_n$ for large enough $n$? It then follows since every $S_n$ is contained in an $S_p$.

Answer (score 5):

First, note that $S_n \subset S_m$ for all $m > n$.

Now Cayley's theorem tells us that, for any finite group $G$, we have $G \cong H$ for some subgroup $H \subset S_{|G|}$.  If we have Cayley's theorem, then we simply choose a prime $p$ larger than $|G|$ and we're done.

To prove Cayley's theorem, consider any $g \in G$ and show that the map $\lambda_g: G \rightarrow G$ defined such that $x \mapsto gx$ is bijective (and thus a permutation of the elements of $G$).

Next, show that the function $\phi:G \rightarrow S_{|G|}$ defined such that $x \mapsto \lambda_x$ is an injective homomorphism.

From there, you can apply the isomorphism theorem to get your desired result.  For now, I'll let you try to fill in the details, and I can expand my answer later on.

Comment: Can this result be used to show that every finite group is the Galois group of an extension $K/F$ where $F$ is itself a finite extension of $Q$?

Comment: @LeonhardLeibniz, Yes.  If I'm not mistaken, it is known that we can always find a $K$ such that $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_n$ for any $n$ desired.  From there, you can apply Galois correspondence between subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ and intermediate fields $\mathbb{Q} \subset E \subset K$, wherein if a subgroup $H \subset \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ corresponds with the subfield $E$, then $H \cong \operatorname{Gal}(K/E)$.